# Синонимизировать [telegram] и [телеграм]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть две абсолютно идентичные метки:

- [telegram](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/telegram) (2203 вопроса, есть описание)
- [телеграм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc) (112 вопросов, нет описания)

Надо бы их синонимизировать в пользу [telegram](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/telegram).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Готово!

```
updating post history, 130 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 112 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 90 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'телеграм': [телеграм] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 2293
tag remapping of [telegram] and [телеграм] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
3 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym телеграм -> telegram was approved!
```